# How to get all child elements (both text and normal) in a reversed way?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   Test 1 
       <b>
           tes
           <i>t</i>
       </b>
       <i>
           zz
       </i>
       test 2
</div>
```

How I would like to get all the child elements in the reversed way, which should be:

1. `test 2` - text node
2. `<i>zz</i>` - node
3. `<b>tes<i>t</i></b>` - node
4. `Test 1` - text node

But I'm having a problem with selecting all nodes... all I keep getting is the 2nd and 3rd node with the `children()` function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `.contents()` ....  Why reversed way ? you can loop it backward anyway.

Comment: And how can the order be reversed?

Comment: `$(yourobject).toArray().reverse();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var c = $('.wrapper').contents();
c = $(c.get().reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(".wrapper").contents();
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)